# Jquery Target all indexed Id in MVC Razor

Tags: jquery, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I dont know what to call or the proper term of this but i want my Indexed fields inside a for loop to add a Jquery Mask for Phone number. I cant target the Id of all the phone in Jquery

Heres my set of codes:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.AdultCount; i++)
{
    <div class="form-group">
         @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CellPhone, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
         <div class="col-md-6">
             @Html.EditorFor(model => model.getAttendeeLists[i].CellPhone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control thisisCp"} })
             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.getAttendeeLists[i].CellPhone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Here I tried adding a Class inside the  EditorFor to be called but to no avail not working properly

```
@section Scripts {   
    @Scripts.Render("~/jquerymask") 
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script>
        $(".thisisCp").mask("?(9999)999-9999");
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Have you also included `jquery-{version}.js`?

Comment: As a side note, your `@Html.LabelFor()` needs to be `@Html.LabelFor(model => model.getAttendeeLists[i].CellPhone)`

Comment: Btw @StephenMuecke Thanks for the help on my previous post, just got 1 step ahead . Yes I added the Jquery Version

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the browser console? (also you edit does not include jquery)

Comment: @StephenMuecke No errors on browser console and added the `.getAttendeeLists[i]` in Labelfor

Comment: Which plugin are you using? And have you include the css file for it (if applicable)?

Comment: Note it works fine in [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CbFM5u) (although not sure why you have the `?` in the mask

Comment: @StephenMuecke is EditorFor and TextboxFor has a difference in rendering? , i Used the (?) to retain the value even entering less than number of the mask

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171053/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-enrique-gil).